# try thrift tornado tutorial get an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'

Tags: python, tornado, thrift

Learn to use thrift, try the tutorial for python tornado. When I started to run PythonClient.py, got the error msg as below:

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback <function null_wrapper at 0x7f38de9bcd70> for <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x7f38de9c1110>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 300, in _set_done
    cb(self)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 149, in final_callback
    if future.result() is not None:
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 876, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "./PythonClient.py", line 58, in communicate
    yield gen.Task(client.ping)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 505, in Task
    func(*args, callback=_argument_adapter(set_result), **kwargs)
TypeError: ping() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'
```

Is there anything wrong with the tutorial?
Here is the source code:
https://git1-us-west.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=tutorial/py.tornado/PythonClient.py;h=005ad3c4d90333946d7c7e90facfd9bc9c43c0d1;hb=HEAD

Comment: "*Is there anything wrong with the tutorial?*"  -  There has been some rewriting in the Python area during the last weeks, mainly for Python 3 support, but not limited to that. So there is a slight chance that something got broken with one of all the possible combinations. I'd suggest to discuss that on the [Thrift user mailing list](https://thrift.apache.org/mailing).

Comment: thanks, i will have a try